# More important than browser's !important

Tags: css, overriding

Is there any way to override `!important` properties defined in browser's CSS code other than using per-element style? It seems that the browsers load their precompiled CSS after page's CSS defined in `style` or `link` tag. I want to remove borders and colors from default checkboxes and radiobuttons (`appearance` is not important so it can be easily disabled), my CSS works in userstyles, but on real web pages it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any page (author) style sheet overrides a browser’s default stylesheet. There is no `!important` in browser stylesheets. Specificity does not matter here, by the rules of the cascade. What matters is that some presentational features are not controllable in CSS in the first place. Demo:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
*  { border: none; }
</style>
<input value=foo><br>
<input type=checkbox checked>
```

This removes the default border of the text input box. On most browsers, it does not affect checkbox rendering, since what we might see as border there is really part of the checkbox widget. IE, as usual, has different behavior, but even on it, you cannot remove the “border,” and if you use your own border on the element, the border is drawn outside the box.

There might be browser-specific ways of affecting their behavior in ways other than standard CSS. You may need to elaborate on what works “in userstyles” and on which browser(s).

Comment: There is !important in browser stylesheet, for example Firefox has it for border and color of checkboxes and radiobuttons (visible with appearance:none). Making them !important in your own stylesheet doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SiPlus, I stand corrected, and Firefox violates the specs, but there doesn’t seem to be anything we can do about it. Setting `-moz-appearance: none` changes the appearance, but it’s still a checkbox, with a box. The only way to create a checkbox with an essentially different approach seems to be to create an element (image or something else) with the desired appearance and associate (with JavaScript) checkbox functionality with it.

Answer (score 0):

So you wanto to "remove" browser default CSS?
I think you can do that with reset CSS, it basicaly resets the browsers styling.
There's many examples out there

Heres one: [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use Javascript to remove the styles from the elements after loading.
Or, design the stylesheet right at first.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is : external css, internal css and inline css. And its overridden order is :

> external < internal < inline.

i.e. external css is overridden by internal and, internal and external is overridden by inline.

Also, we can update it through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your styles, using selectors that are at least as specific as the original selectors.
2. Mark your overriding styles with !important
3. Declare/include your stylesheet **after** the existing styles

Here's an example, where the last !important styles declared take priority over earlier styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/8QHQk/1/